# what is the right selector for a checked input and a label with same parent?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

there is a parent element for exam ".subNav" and that includes 4 input elements and 4 label linked to input.

```
<nav class="subNav">
    <input type="radio" name="subNav" id="s1">              
    <input type="radio" name="subNav" id="s2">
    <input type="radio" name="subNav" id="s3">
    <input type="radio" name="subNav" id="s4">
    <label for="s1"><h2>S1</h2></label>
    <label for="s2"><h2>S2</h2></label>
    <label for="s3"><h2>S3</h2></label>
    <label for="s4"><h2>S4</h2></label>
</nav>
```

i want when one of input checked, it's label get different background-color. but i dont know waht is the right selector to do that. i used below selector but that not work correctly:

```
#s1:checked ~ label:nth-child(1){ background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

so what is the right selector?

Comment: Would be easier if you could give the labels an id too. Or change the HTML, so that each input is immediately followed by its label, then you could use the adjacent sibling combinator `+`

Comment: Give you labels IDs and it will become a piece of cake :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put ID's on your labels but this is how to make it without ID's :

`#s1:checked ~ label[for="s1"]`

See this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b6uRc/

Comment: i did it but its work in mine just when i click in first label. for second click its not work and just the first clicked label has chenged. whats the wrong you think?

Comment: Try removing your `h2`. You should not put them in labels. They are block elements and label are inline elements. Never put blocks into inlines.

Comment: huh i found it, there was inheritance issues. thanks for answer :)